# Ubuntu server root on ZFS mirror

Tags: server, zfs, mirrors

Is it possible to install Ubuntu Server (root) on a ZFS mirrored pool. E.g.

ssd1

- partition1
- partition2

ssd2

- partition3
- partition4

Then create a ZFS mirrored pool 'root' with partitions 1+3 and install Ubuntu Server on 'root'
Second create a ZFS mirrored pool 'home' with partitions 2+4

Would it make more sense to have root on two separate disks?

Comment: Does it make sense to have  mirror ? Yes off-course, for the added security that you don't loos data if a disk breaks. Is it best practice to use partitions for ZFS pools: No - use full disks. But in this case, I don't think that it will break anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above should *definitely* be possible by following the ["Root on ZFS"](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Getting%20Started/Ubuntu/Ubuntu%2020.04%20Root%20on%20ZFS.html) how-to; the only step which differs is the creation of the pool(s), after all. However, you should be aware of the fact that "non-ZFS partitions" (e.g., EFI) on said discs should be mirrored/kept in sync at all times as well in order to ensure that the system can still be booted if one of them fails; this has already been hinted [elsewhere](https://saveriomiroddi.github.io/Installing-Ubuntu-on-a-ZFS-root-with-encryption-and-mirroring/#boot-vs-bootefi). You might want to check out [Saverio Miroddi's "zfs-installer" repository on GitHub](https://github.com/saveriomiroddi/zfs-installer).